# Python как использовать шаблоны для формирования xml?

Tags: python, xml, шаблоны

Есть xml файл. Хочу заполнять его через скрипт. Для простоты пусть будет такая структура:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <test name ="test 1" work="1">
        <fname>/home/user/files/file_1.txt</fname>
        <hash>1dcd4a5bfc2c04b37816f5da6ba0ab7d</hash>
        <cnt_out>2</cnt_out>
    </test>
    <test name ="test 2" work="1">
        <fname>/home/user/files/file_2.txt</fname>
        <hash>f71214861111f444bee958e6b5c758ce</hash>
        <cnt_out>2</cnt_out>
    </test>
</data>
```

Есть возможность добавлять новые блоки  через шаблон ? Ожидание - определение переменных (в примере 5 штук), заполнение шаблона и добавление к файлу.

Comment: А что вы уже попробовали? Что не работает? Есть варианты с `xml.etree`, `lxml`, `Beautiful Soup`.

Comment: Только читаю xml.tree Вопрос не в том как добавить узел, дочерние и т.д. а в том как это сделать через шаблон (привычка от РНР осталась).

Comment: Тогда смотрите, как используется [ElementTree.write()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#modifying-an-xml-file) и [SubElement()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#building-xml-documents)

Comment: Если именно шаблоны (например, jinja2), то точно так же как для любого другого текстового формата.

Answer (score 0):

я начинающий, к тому же перешедший с РНР, еще не привык к Python. Вот нашел то что нужно - пример шаблона и работы с ним
https://gist.github.com/kohsah/99c411a3415d1a49b30e9da711558226

Comment: А, вы буквально. =) 
Тогда есть [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting), [str.format()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples) и старое %-форматирование, которое можно не смотреть.